# Why do we need karma-test-shim.js

Tags: .net, angular, karma-jasmine

Currently, I am learning how to setup karma testing on Angular 2 setup given in following link.

https://github.com/angular/quickstart

But i am not very much clear on the fact of using karma-test-shim.js file.

Could anyone enlighten me on this ?

Answer (score 4):

The `karma-test-shim.js` file is used to import the spec files with SystemJS. When the Karma test runner is started, no files get added as scripts. They need to be loaded through SystemJS.

All that file does is filter all the spec files, using the `.spec` naming conventions, then loads them. Only the spec files need to be loaded with SystemJS, because all the spec files will already import the application files, which import Angular files. And those spec files run as soon as they get loaded by SystemJS

Also in that file is a SytemJS mappings for Angular tests files. For example

```
'@angular/core/testing': 'npm:@angular/core/testing/core-testing.umd.js'
```

The `systemjs.config.js` file maps all the non-testing Angular modules, which are used for the application. We don't include the testing modules in there because the testing files don't need to be mapped in the application, only for testing.

**See also:**

- [Angular 2 Testing with Karma and SystemJS](https://psamsotha.github.io/angular/2016/12/16/angular2-testing-karma-systemjs.html) for a comprehensive walk-through of the configuration.

Comment: Thank you for the information it is defiantly..  Just in scenarioi I want to change the root folder within karma-test-shim.js file should i change in system config section ? does this consider app folder as a root folder or can i give any path in the solution ?

Comment: is this necessary in an app using webpack? (e.g. standard set up for Ionic 3)

Comment: I still confused with different baseURL as my app inside another folder called 'SPA'. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50943815/systemjs-config-with-baseurl-in-angular